# Sum values, avoid duplications, and render on a Ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, duplication

I have a Model just like this

```
Name  **  Money Flow

Bob       +100
Jacky     -130
Bob       -20
Charles   +30
Jacky     +10
```

And I want to render it in my view as

```
Name  **  Money Flow

Bob       +80
Jacky     -120
Charles   +30
```

So I want to avoid duplication of the name, and I want to sum the flows for each name.

Do you have an idea how i can do that ? For now I'm only using a normal loop to display all:

```
Model.all.each do |model|
    <%= model.name %>
    <%= model.money_flow %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: what is your requirement...do you want to add all models using an attribute common in them or something else...??

Comment: I think you need to group_by model name and then do sum of model.

Comment: @NicoFerna, yes it is almost the same ! Thx !